# Chromedriver not detecting GPS location as "Insecure origins treated as secure" not set

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver with chrome version - "**Version 107.0.5304.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) with Windows 10**" and I am using website where it will automatically detect GPS location. This is not happening as we have to set "Insecure origins treated as secure" flag. When i pause execution and set the "Insecure origins treated as secure" it worked fine.

For Automation testing I am using **Java** with **TestNG** and need to know how can i enable/Set "Insecure origins treated as secure" using java code. Something like chrome.option(--Insecure origins treated as secure, 'myurl').

Note- I have tried giving command line argument in the IntelliJ IDEA but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After researching and experimenting I got this solution -

I have added this code to set "Insecure origins treated as secure" while initializing chromedriver and its options.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://myurl.com/");
```

I may have deleted this question but thought its better to answer so that others can use it. Hope it helped.

Comment: You little beauty. I always appreciate it when someone comes back to answer their question after working it out.